# Can multiple tables have same composite keys? Spring boot + Spring Data JPA + Oracle

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables - SALES and ITEMS with no primary keys defined. I need to create the entities for the two tables and their composite keys since these tables doesn't have a primary key. Two properties both the table contains are:

1. Store number
2. OrderNumber

Can multiple tables have the same composite keys? If not how can I have a composite key in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, no problem. The only restriction is that those primary key constraints can't have the same name.

```
SQL> create table a (store number, corder number);

Table created.

SQL> create table b (store number, corder number);

Table created.

SQL> alter table a add constraint pka primary key (store, corder);

Table altered.

SQL> alter table b add constraint pka primary key (store, corder);
alter table b add constraint pka primary key (store, corder)
                             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint


SQL> alter table b add constraint pkb primary key (store, corder);

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Comment: Alright. I would be creating an Embeddable class (SalesPK) and embed it into the Sales.java class. The SalesPK class will have two properties (composite key): sales_no and order_no. The same goes for Order.java class. It will have Id property of type OrderPK, which is an embeddable class with properties: sales_no and order_no. Hope that will work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand anything that follows "Alright". I don't speak Java so ... I'm pretty much useless about it. But, as of Oracle (database) part of the story, then yes - you can have such primary keys, as my example shows. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @ Littlefoot